# Ruby armstrong numbers in a range

Tags: ruby, numbers, range

```
puts "Enter range(starts at 1), ends at the number that you enter: "
range = gets.chomp.to_i


number = 1

while number <= range
    temporary_number = number
    sum_angstrom = 0
    number += number

    while(temporary_number != 0)
        digit = temporary_number % 10
        temporary_number /= 10
        sum_angstrom = sum_angstrom + (digit ** 3)
    end

    if (sum_angstrom == number)
        puts number
    end
end
```

This time, I tried to make a program to show the armstrong numbers in a range that's taken from the user's input. The program just stops after I enter the number and press enter and i can't figure out why.

Keep in mind that i can't use for(each), that's why i'm using while so often.

Comment: Actually the program does not stops. You'll only see anything print if the condition `sum_angstrom == number` is met. You can use some `puts` to debug you program.

Comment: Hmm, it should normally print, 1 153 370 371 407, i'll keep trying.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the way im iterating (number += number) through the numbers.

Comment: @AllenM if I'm not mistaken, each digit has to be raised to the power of the number of total digits. That's 3 for 3-digit numbers `153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3`, 4 for 4-digit numbers `1634  = 1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4` and so on. See https://oeis.org/A005188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change `number += number` to `number += 1`; otherwise you will only test the powers of 2.

Second, move the `number += 1` line at the bottom of the while block it is in. Otherwise you will always test if `sum_armstrong(n) == n+1`.

This [works](http://ideone.com/SNXRtB):

```
puts "Enter range(starts at 1), ends at the number that you enter: "
range = gets.chomp.to_i


number = 1

while number <= range
    temporary_number = number
    sum_angstrom = 0

    while(temporary_number != 0)
        digit = temporary_number % 10
        temporary_number /= 10
        sum_angstrom = sum_angstrom + (digit ** 3)
    end

    if (sum_angstrom == number)
        puts number
    end

    number += 1
end
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i did before seeing your answer, i knew there was something wrong with the way i was iterating XD.

Answer (score 0):

**Armstrong Number in Ruby one liner**

```
n  = 153 
s = 0 
n.to_s.split("").map{|e| s+=(e.to_i*e.to_i*e.to_i)}
puts (n==s ? "Armstrong number" : "Not Armstrong number")
```

You can iterate in a range to print the value based on your requirement. 
Main logic lies in below line.

```
 n.to_s.split("").map{|e| s+=(e.to_i*e.to_i*e.to_i)}
```

**Improving my answer a little bit**

```
n.digits.map{|e| s+=(e**3)}
```